# How to show for a distribution $T$ and a test function $\varphi,~~T'[\varphi]\equiv -T[\varphi']\;?$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, distribution-theory

> For a generalized
>   function $T,$ we define
>   $$T'[\varphi] ~≡~ −T[φ']~~~~~~\forall φ ∈ \mathcal D(Ω).$$
>
> where $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ denotes the test function space.

I'm not getting how they deduced this relation. Can anyone tell me how to prove the relation?

Comment: if $T_n$ is a differentiable function, integrating by parts : $\int_{-\infty}^\infty T_n(x) \varphi'(x) dx =  -\int_{-\infty}^\infty T_n'(x) \varphi(x) dx$ then consider such a sequence converging to $T$ in the sense of distributions so that $T \varphi'= \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n \varphi'  = -\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n' \varphi = -T' \varphi $

Comment: I'm not an expert but I would say that it's the definition. It is the natural extension of the $C^1$ case. In fact given $f \in C^1$ you would agree that $T_f'(\phi)=\int f'\phi = -\int f\phi'=-T_f(\phi')$, where we used integration by parts and the fact that $\phi$ is compactly supported.

Comment: This is the definition. As @Maffred points out, it is consistent with the $C^1$ case.

Comment: @Maffred: +1; I really would like to see that as an answer.

Comment: you should think to the ways for creating such a sequence of smooth functions $T_n$ from a distribution : take any [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) $\phi(x) \ge 0$, shift it and stretch it $\phi_{n,x}(y) = \frac{\phi(n(x- y) )}{n} $and consider $T_n(x) = T[\phi_{n,x}]$, finally show that $T[\varphi] = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty T_n(x) \varphi(x) dx$

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in some comments, this is the definition of distributional derivative. In general, if $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$ is a multi-index, the distributional derivative of order $\alpha$, of a distribution $T \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ is defined by placing

$(\star)$ $\displaystyle \langle D^\alpha T, \varphi \rangle =(-1)^{|\alpha|} \langle T, D^\alpha \varphi \rangle$ $\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$

It is still a distribution, so $D^{\alpha}T \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ and it is essentially a generalization of the rule of integration by parts in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, every $f \in L_{loc}^1(\Omega)$ determines a distribution $T_f$ defined by

$\displaystyle T_{f}(\varphi):= \int_{\Omega} f \varphi dx $ $\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$

Then, for example, if $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ we have $f' \in C(\mathbb{R})$ and  it is locally integrable, then we can define the distribution

$\displaystyle T_{f'}(\varphi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x) \varphi(x) dx = f(x)\varphi(x) \vert_{|x|=\infty} - \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \varphi'(x) dx = -T_{f}(\varphi')$

since $\varphi$ vanishes at infinity. Now $(\star)$ is the generalization of these facts in the distribution space.